How to find the actual version of an Azure VM extension using PowerShell
I have already pulled out of the Azure region the latest extension versions of the extensions we have installed (using Get-AzVmImagePublisher -Location "location" | Get-AzVMExtensionImageType | Get-AzVMExtensionImage | Select Type, Version) and I would like accurate information of the extension versions of our VMs so we know which ones need updating - else we either have to do it manually through the portal or in a blanket approach updating extensions of all VMs irrespective of the version.
I can find the Typehandler version of a Azure VM extension using Get-AzVMExtension (or (Get-AzVM).extensions) but often this does not line up with the actual version of the extension you can see when you are viewing the VM in the portal and click on the extension and check the Version field. And I have two test Windows VMs at the moment with the same version of the AzureMonitoringAgent extension installed (1.29.0.0) but one VM shows its TypehandlerVersion (as reported using PowerShell) as 1.0 and the other shows 1.9.
I understand that this may be as far as PowerShell takes us but no harm in asking, thank you.
